# xrpl-py testnet is not a valid url

Tags: python, xrp

I am new to cryptocurrencies in general and I am at an intermediate level in Python (but a new Websocket user). I am using the xrpl-py library in order to build a Ripple-ledger based App, however I am getting stuck at the very beginning.

When I try to run the following

```
testnet_url = "https://s.altnet.rippletest.net:51234"

from xrpl.clients import WebsocketClient

client = WebsocketClient(testnet_url)
client.open()    #This usage for opening the client is not preferred, but is useful for reproducing the error
```

I get the following error:

> File
> "/home/gordito/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/uri.py",
> line 70, in parse_uri
> raise InvalidURI(uri) from exc
>
> InvalidURI: https://s.altnet.rippletest.net:51234 isn't a valid URI

Am I trying to connect to the wrong url? This is the only address listed in the XRP documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you connect to a websocket, the URL should start with `wss://` and not `https://`.

A list of public endpoints to connect to can be found here:

https://xrpl.org/public-servers.html

so in your example, the URL should be:

`wss://s.altnet.rippletest.net/`

if you use `https://` then you call the JSON-RPC endpoint and not the websocket endpoint.

Best,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning to connect to the test net like this, using JavaScript:

```
const api = new xrpl.Client("wss://s.altnet.rippletest.net/");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).